# Chart.js update function (chart,labels,data) will not update the chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I cannot debug the following code. I would like to update chart data (not add on top; delete current data and add completely new dataset). (Not)Working example on codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvBxpr

```
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
       label: "My First dataset",
       data: [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
       fill: false
    }]
   }
 };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

    labelsNew = ["Why", "u", "no", "work", "???"];
    dataNew = [2, 4, 5, 6, 10];

    function updateData(chart, label, data) {
      removeData();
      chart.data.labels.push(label);
      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
      });
      chart.update();
    };

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}

$('.button-container').on('click', 'button', updateData(myChart, labelsNew, dataNew));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. This works:

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels = label
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = data;
    });
    chart.update();
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
addData (myChart, labelsNew, dataNew);
});
```

instead of pushing the data (which adds on), data needs to be allocated by " = ".

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems:

- in function `updateData()` missing chart argument to  `removeData(chart);`
- click handler for button, use simply:

  `$("#btn").click(function() {
      updateData(myChart, labelsNew, dataNew)
  });`

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing them two. Your solution adds data onto the chart, I am after replacing the data completely.

Comment: It is useful, but it does not solve the problem. I will vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
       label: "My First dataset",
       data: [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
       fill: false
    }]
   }
 };

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

labelsNew = ["Why", "u", "no", "work", "???"];
dataNew = [2, 4, 5, 6, 10];

function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels = label
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = data;
    });
    chart.update();
}

function clickupdate(){
  addData(myChart, labelsNew, dataNew);
}
```

```css
.chart-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div class="button-container">
  <button onclick="clickupdate()">Change Data</button>
</div>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```